# Should "not P" be interpreted as "P implies a contradiction"?

Tags: logic, philosophy

From [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64736/how-does-mathematics-work?answertab=votes#tab-top),

```
(...) "not P" should be interpreted as the assertion "P implies a contradiction".
```

Is this the (only/widespread/mainly) accepted definition of the negation of a statement? For me, it definitely makes sense, as a false statement ultimately leads to the negation of an axiom.

Comment: In certain unusual types of logic (intuitionistic, three-valued, etc.), the usual relations may not be true, so it may be useful to define "not P" somehow.  But in the conventional logic, "not" is one of the primitives.

Comment: "the most widespread definition of the negation of a statement" is : "the negation of a statement P is TRUE iff P is FALSE".

Comment: The are so many different ways to conceptualize negation, and you haven't given your purpose for wanting to conceptualize it, so this question really doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Don't over think this. In classical logic, when you see the proposition P, you can interpret it as "P is true." When you see the proposition ~P, you can interpret it as "P is false."

Comment: As a side node: $\neg P$ is very often *defined* as $P \to \bot$, if one takes the connectives $\to$ and $\bot$ as primitive and $\neg$ only as syntactic sugar, as is sometimes done for reasons of simplicity. This is consistent not only with the semantics of classical logic (just check out the truth table), but is indeed the most natural interpretation of negation in intuitionstic logic, where truth tables and many of the known equivalences of classical logic (such as $p \equiv \neg \neg p$) are not applicable. ...

Comment: ... With classical and intuitionistic logic, you already have the two most "popular" logics covered (if one can dare to measure such a thing as popularity), so you can take it as fairly widely accepted that the one can indeed be interpreted as the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $P$ is logically equivalent to $\neg P\Rightarrow\text{false}$ and is the basis of the proof of contradictio. This coincides with your observation.

Comment: I would be a bit more careful, because the fact that $P$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \to \bot$ holds in classical logic but not in other weaker and well-studied logics such as intuitionistic logic. But also in intuitionistic logic $\lnot P$ should be interpreted as $P \to \bot$, i.e.  $P$ implies contradiction. In other words, your answer explains the classical case, but the question has a positive answer also in other cases.